# Calling Convention conflict in Outputpin

Tags: c++, directshow

I got the following error when trying to connect my filters output pin to another filter.

[image]

This is the line that triggered the error (in the outputpin code)

```
HRESULT hr = pPin->GetAllocatorRequirements(pprops);
```

Here the function declaration:

```
class MCMyOutputPin : public CBaseOutputPin
{
    ....
    HRESULT CheckMediaType(const CMediaType *pmt);
    HRESULT SetMediaType(const CMediaType *pmt);
    HRESULT CompleteConnect(IPin *pReceivePin);
    //virtual HRESULT __stdcall Connect(IPin* pPin, const AM_MEDIA_TYPE *pmt);
    HRESULT BreakConnect();
    HRESULT GetMediaType(int i, CMediaType *pmt);
    HRESULT DecideBufferSize(IMemAllocator *pAlloc, ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES *pProps);
    HRESULT DecideAllocator(IMemInputPin *pPin, IMemAllocator **ppAlloc);
    HRESULT Deliver(IMediaSample* sample);
    BOOL IsConnected();

    ...
```

I believe DecideAllocator is called by GetAllocatorRequirements.

According to msdn ([Building DirectShw Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) functions must be declared with __stdcall.
So there seems to be a calling conventin conflict between the calling and the called function.
However if i try to set the functions to __stdcall:

```
HRESULT __stdcall DecideAllocator(IMemInputPin *pPin, IMemAllocator **ppAlloc);
```

I get the compile error:

> 'MCMyOutputPin::DecideAllocator': overriding virtual function differs
>   from 'CBaseOutputPin::DecideAllocator' only by calling convention

So I tried to make sure the baseclasses are built using stdcall calling convention: 
I opened the baseclasses project (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses)  And set

> ConfigurationProperties->C/C++->Advanced->Calling Convention
>   to __stdcall(/Gz)

So in summary:

- I believe I have calling convention conflict
- I can't change the calling convention in my code
- Setting the calling convention in the baseclasses project and recompiling still doesn't solve the problem

But I still can't change the calling convention of the outputpins functions of my project to stdcall

Update:

This my filters NonDelegatingQueryInterface:

```
STDMETHODIMP MyFilter::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
    if(riid == IID_IMyInterfilter) {
        mylogger->LogDebug("In Nondelegationqueryinterface", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
        return GetInterface((IMyFilter*)this, ppv);
    }

    else 
    {
        return CBaseFilter::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(riid, ppv);
    }
}
```

Here the filters header:

```
class MyFilter : public  CBaseFilter, public IMyFilter
{
public: 

    CCritSec lockfilter;
    DECLARE_IUNKNOWN;

    const LONGLONG MEDIATIME = 5;

    MyFilter(LPUNKNOWN pUnk, HRESULT* phr);
    virtual ~MyFilter(void);

     virtual int  GetPinCount();
    virtual CBasePin*  GetPin(int n);

    STDMETHODIMP Run(REFERENCE_TIME tStart);
    STDMETHODIMP Pause();
    STDMETHODIMP Stop();

    void acceptFilterInput(LPCWSTR pinname, IMediaSample* sample);
    CMyInputPin* getPreviousPIN(LPCWSTR pinname);
    CMyInputPin* getNextPIN(LPCWSTR pinname);
    //BOOL requestRecordMode(LPCWSTR pinname); //returns false if previous pin thread is not sleeping

    static CUnknown* WINAPI CreateInstance(LPUNKNOWN pUnk, HRESULT *phr);
    STDMETHODIMP NonDelegatingQueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppv);

    //STDMETHODIMP   StartRecording();
    STDMETHODIMP  GetThePinCount(int* result);
    //STDMETHODIMP StopRecording();
    STDMETHOD_(IPin*,GetMyPin)(int index);

    //STDMETHODIMP Next(ULONG cPins, IPin** pppins, ULONG fetched);
    //STDMETHODIMP Clone(IEnumPins **ppenum);
    //STDMETHODIMP Reset();
    //STDMETHODIMP Skip(ULONG cpins);
    //

    CCritSec m_lock_filter;

    TimeGiver* m_pTimeGiver;    

    MCMyOutputPin *outpin;
    static const int COUNT_INPUTPINS = 3;
    static unsigned __stdcall workerthreadfunc(void *);
    HANDLE workerThreadHandle;
private:

    MyLogger *mylogger;
    CCritSec m_critSec;
    bool running;




    LPCWSTR currentInputPin;

    void startSyncThread();






     CMyInputPin* GetPinByName(LPCWSTR name);

     LONGLONG* mediaTimeBuffer;


     CMyInputPin* inputpins[COUNT_INPUTPINS];

};
```

Here is the filters implementation:

```
#include "MyInputPin.h"
#include "CMyOutPutPin.h"
#include "MyLogger.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



MyFilter::MyFilter(LPUNKNOWN pUnk, HRESULT* phr) : CBaseFilter(NAME("MyFilter"), pUnk, &lockfilter, CLSID_MyInterFilter)
{


    HRESULT *hr_0 = NOERROR;
    HRESULT *hr_1 = NOERROR;
    HRESULT* hr_2 = NOERROR;
    HRESULT* hr_3 = NOERROR;


    inputpins[0] = new CMyInputPin(TEXT("PIN0"), L"PIN0", pUnk, this, &this->m_lock_filter, hr_0, 0);
    inputpins[1] = new CMyInputPin(TEXT("PIN1"), L"PIN1", pUnk, this, &this->m_lock_filter, hr_1, 1);
    inputpins[2] = new CMyInputPin(TEXT("PIN2"), L"PIN2", pUnk, this, &this->m_lock_filter, hr_2, 2);
    outpin = new MCMyOutputPin(this, hr_3, TEXT("PINOUT0"));
    this->running = false;
    mylogger = new MyLogger();

    mylogger->LogDebug("Construtor of Filter", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");

    m_pTimeGiver = new TimeGiver(2, MEDIATIME);








}

CMyInputPin* MyFilter::getPreviousPIN(LPCWSTR pinname)
{
    CMyInputPin *inpin = GetPinByName(pinname);
    int position = inpin->m_position;
    int adjused = position + COUNT_INPUTPINS - 1;
    int newInex = adjused % COUNT_INPUTPINS;
    return inputpins[newInex];

}
CMyInputPin* MyFilter::getNextPIN(LPCWSTR pinname)
{
    CMyInputPin *inpin = GetPinByName(pinname);
    int position = inpin->m_position;
    int incremented = position++;
    int newIndex = incremented % COUNT_INPUTPINS;
    return inputpins[newIndex];
}
//BOOL MyFilter::requestRecordMode(LPCWSTR pinname) { //returns false if previous pin thread is not sleeping
//  for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_INPUTPINS; i++)
//  {
//      if (wcscmp(pinname, inputpins[i]->Name()) == 0)
//      {
//          inputpins[i]->m_bIsSleeping = false;
//      }
//      else {
//          inputpins[i]->m_bIsSleeping = true;
//      }
// 
//  }
//  return TRUE;
//}


HRESULT MyFilter::Run(REFERENCE_TIME tStart)
{
    mylogger->LogDebug("In MyFilter::Run:", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
    CAutoLock cobjectlock(&m_critSec);  
    workerThreadHandle = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, workerthreadfunc, (void *)this, 0, NULL);
    //boost::thread workerThread(&MyFilter::startSyncThread, this);
    m_tStart = tStart;
    if (m_State == State_Stopped){
        HRESULT hr = Pause();

        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            return hr;
        }
    }


    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT MyFilter::Stop()
{
    mylogger->LogDebug("In MyFilter::Stop:", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
    CAutoLock cobjectlock(&m_critSec);
    m_State = State_Stopped;
    this->m_pTimeGiver->stop();
    //this->m_thread.join();
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT MyFilter::Pause()
{
    CAutoLock cobjectlock(&m_critSec);
    m_State = State_Paused;

    mylogger->LogDebug("In MyFilter::PAuse:", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");

    return S_OK;
}



MyFilter::~MyFilter(void)
{


    //delete mylogger;



    //delete outpin;
    //delete[] inputpins;

}

int  MyFilter::GetPinCount()
{
    return COUNT_INPUTPINS + 1; //One outputpin

}

IPin* MyFilter::GetMyPin(int n)
{

    CBasePin* pin = this->GetPin(n);
    return pin;

}

CBasePin*  MyFilter::GetPin(int n)
{
    if (n >= 0 && n < COUNT_INPUTPINS)
    {
        return inputpins[n];

    }
    if (n == 3)
    {
        return outpin;
    }
    return NULL;
}

//HRESULT MyFilter::GetThePinCount(int *result)
//{
//  *result = 4;
//}

HRESULT MyFilter::GetThePinCount(int* giveme)
{
    *giveme = COUNT_INPUTPINS + 1;
    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyFilter::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
    if(riid == IID_IMyInterfilter) {
        mylogger->LogDebug("In Nondelegationqueryinterface", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
        return GetInterface((IMyFilter*)this, ppv);
    }

    else 
    {
        return CBaseFilter::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(riid, ppv);
    }
}

/*RESULT MyFilter::StartRecording()
{
    this->running = true;
    return S_OK;

}*/
//
//HRESULT MyFilter::StopRecording()
//{
//  this->running = false;
//  return S_OK;
//
//}

CUnknown* WINAPI MyFilter::CreateInstance(LPUNKNOWN pUnk, HRESULT *phr)
{

    CUnknown* pNewFilter = new MyFilter(pUnk, phr);

    if (phr)
    {
        if (pNewFilter == NULL) 
            *phr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        else
            *phr = S_OK;
    }

    return pNewFilter;
}


void MyFilter::acceptFilterInput(LPCWSTR pinname, IMediaSample* sample)
{

    mylogger->LogDebug("In acceptFIlterInput", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
    outpin->Deliver(sample);

}
//STDMETHODIMP MyFilter::Next(ULONG cPins, IPin** pppins, ULONG fetched)
//{
//
//}
//STDMETHODIMP MyFilter::(IEnumPins **ppenum)
//{
//
//}
//STDMETHODIMP MyFilter::Reset()
//{
//
//}
//STDMETHODIMP MyFilter::Skip(ULONG cpins)
//{
//
//}




CMyInputPin* MyFilter::GetPinByName(LPCWSTR name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_INPUTPINS; i++)
    {
        if (wcscmp(name, inputpins[0]->Name()))
        {
            return inputpins[0];
        }
    }


    return NULL;
}


void MyFilter::startSyncThread()
{
    this->m_pTimeGiver->start();
}

unsigned int  MyFilter::workerthreadfunc(void * param)
{
    MyFilter* myfilter;
    myfilter = (MyFilter *)param;
    myfilter->m_pTimeGiver->start();
    return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong calling convention is a typical problem to get this error message, however it is only one of the possible causes. The same mismatch can be "achieved" by bad pointer cast when, for instance, you are expected to return `IFooA*` pointer, and you return `IFooB*` instead. Then call `IFooA::BarA` executes effectively your `IFooB::BarB` code and their syntax/call differences result is stack frame failures. I believe this is the case you are having since it's not so easy to build with wrong calling convention on specific interface/method only.

The problem should be definitely around the interface you have debugger stopped at. I'd start checking from `NonDelegatingQueryInterface` implementation to make sure you return proper interfaces, which match correctly requested `IID`s.

UPD. Whatever the original problem is, this does not look good at all:

```
CMyInputPin* MyFilter::GetPinByName(LPCWSTR name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_INPUTPINS; i++)
    {
        // 1. you want [i], not [0]
        // 2. you want if(wcscmp(...) == 0)
        if (wcscmp(name, inputpins[0]->Name()))
        {
            // 3. you want [i], not [0]
            return inputpins[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: so the problem is in the filter and not the pin? Because the pin is not a com class and has no NoDelegatingQueryInterface method.

Comment: Pin is definitely a COM object too, it implements interfaces in particular. The problem might be in bad cast, however there is no information to add anything more detailed.

Comment: I haved added some more code. Hope this is the information you need to help me.